# Built-in voltage

Tags: voltage, semiconductors

Hello all I have work on the following question and just wondering if you all could check to see if i did it correctly.

The built-in voltage of a GaAs pn junction diode is 1.25 V when the diode's temperature is T = 320 K. The cathode region of the diode is doped with phosphorus at a concentration of 1017 cm-3. Determine the required doping concentration in the anode region.

I will attach my work.

Thanks a lot!
[image]

Comment: It perfectly acceptable, and actually recommended that you provide the worked out solution in your original question.  You may even answer it as a separate answer.  starting another question that is essentially a variant of the original question is not how this site is setup.

Comment: Im sorry I honestly didn't remember I posted that. I've been working on this stuff all day and must have gotten lost in it all. Wont happen again

Comment: @rawbrawb I udnerstand you helped me find the formula to use in the previous question. But I do not think that that question solves the question I asked above.

Comment: Add it in to the original, the idea is to use questions to build a reference base.  That's why people may not answer homework questions directly but will help and guide, especially if the working details are posted.  This isn't about being a service to provide answers but a way to capture knowledge and examples.  It's perfectly OK to modify the original question, just note that fact.

Comment: Okay, so delete this one and add it to the last?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8857/discussion-between-rawbrawb-and-philliesws10)